# I have to click twice on my submit button before js run. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, linux

I have a little problem. Why do I have to click twice on my submit button before my js script run? I want that when I click the button the data are send, and the js script runs without click again
This is my page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js-scripts.js"></script>
  <style>
  .content {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .test{
    width:200px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content" id="tot-op">
  <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <center>
      <div class="content" id="tot-op">
        <fieldset>
          <input type="number" min="1" max="7" name="num" required>
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Invia" onclick="hide()">
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </center>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div id="insert" style="display:none">
    <?php
    $test=$_POST["num"];
    echo $test;
    ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my script:

```
function hide(){
     document.getElementById("tot-op").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("insert").style.display = "block";
  }
```

What can I do?

Comment: When you click 1st time, the form gets submitted, right? And then you click again and the js script runs?

Comment: @MathewsMathai yes. it functions like you said

Comment: That's because 1st time you fill out the form and then the `submit `action works since you have fulfilled all the requirements and the 2nd time you may have clicked the button without filling out the form. So, submission doesn't take place but `onclick` is triggered. Fill out the form again before 2nd click and check what happens.

Comment: @MathewsMathai is like the 1st time

Comment: I didn't get you. Did you fill form for both the clicks?

Comment: @MathewsMathai yes. the 1st time i fill with 1 and the 2nd time I changed value. When I clicked again it has shown the 2nd value

Comment: I understand that you want the form to be submitted and the `div` to be hidden at one click. Can you post the `php code` too? I will show you how to do it easily without using `onclick`.

Comment: Which php code? @MathewsMathai

Comment: The one which handles the form data on submitting.

Comment: @MathewsMathai do you mean this?
<?php
    $test=$_POST["num"];
    echo $test;
    ?>

Comment: Yep. I just noticed that you already had it in there. Sorry. :D

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` attribute to your form like:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="test-form">
```

Change your button definition to:

```
<input type="button" value="Invia" onclick="hide()">
```

and then, inside your `hide()` add the form submit action like:

```
function hide()
{
    document.getElementById("test-form").submit();

    document.getElementById("tot-op").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("insert").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: And what happens if the button is clicked without filling out the `required` field? The `onclick` call will work anyway, right?

Comment: @teddo change your input button definition from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. The submit action will be done inside your `hide()` JS script instead.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi Does `document.getElementById("test-form").submit()` check if `required` fields have been filled out? Just curious.

Comment: @MathewsMathai to validate the form you can add `onsubmit` to the form like described here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can always break out of `php` and run javascript code or manipulate HTML using conditional blocks. Below the `<script>` tag will be added to the document only if condition returns `true`.
It is similar to `echo "<script>...</script>"`.

> So, your form data gets handled and also the Javascript code runs the
>   way you want it.

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST["sButton"]) ) //I had done a mistake here
{ //start if
//close php and add script which will run only if the variable $_POST["num"] is set
?>  

<script>
document.getElementById("tot-op").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("insert").style.display = "block";
</script>

<?php
//start php again and complete the if block
$test=$_POST["num"];
echo $test;
} //end of if block
?>
```

> Set a name for your submit button. I have used `sButton` here and use
>   `if( isset($_POST["sButton"]) )`. I made changes above and remove `onclick`. It is not required here.

```
<input type="submit" name="sButton" value="Invia">
```

Comment: Do I have to copy this code on my php code?  Do I have to change the submit button into a normal button?

Comment: You could replace your php code with this and try if it works the way you want. I just edited `<script>...</script>`. Keep the `input` type as `submit`.

Comment: I had initially used `if( !isset($_POST["num"]) )`. I typed that exclamatory mark by mistake. Exclamatory mark makes it `if(false ) then enter` and we want to enter `if true` that is if some value was set. You could either remove that exclamatory mark and `onclick` and keep everything else the same or use the `submit button instead of using the name field`. If you use `submit button`, give it a `name` and use that `name` like it shows in my edited answer.